# Can't use a variable for my array size but variable is declared as a const int

Tags: c++, arrays, constants

So I am having an issue with not being able to make a new array with a variable size (the variable is declared as `const int`)

Here is the code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int newArraySize;

int main ()
{
   std::cin >> newArraySize;

   int const fin = newArraySize;

   int deduped[fin]; // Here is the error
}
```

The error I'm getting is

> Error: Expression must have a constant value

I tried casting as a constant but still no luck (same error)

```
int const fin = const_cast<int const&>(newArraySize);
int deduped[fin];
```

Comment: The problem is with `newArraySize`, not `fin`. `newArraySize` isn't const.

Comment: You have other errors too, like `for (int n = 0; n=20; n++)` a couple of times. And a nasty one, `if (10 > temp > 110)`. But anyway, does `deduped` ever outgrow `duper`? If not, why don't you just make them the same size?

Answer (score 3):

C++ has (confusingly) *two* forms of `const`.  Your `fin` is one type, but the *other* type is required for something to be the size of an array.  The other type is newly called `constexpr`, and used to be "a compile-time constant".  You see, all arrays have to be a fixed size known to the compiler in C++.  So it's not enough to make a variable `const`, the compiler has to be able to figure out the *value* as well. So either `newArraySize` must be a compile time constant expression, or, more likely, you'll have to use a dynamic array, preferably managed by `std::vector`.

```
std::vector<int> deduped(newArraySize);
```

If you can't use a `vector`, there's other (worse) options: `std::unique_ptr<int[]>`, managing, dynamic memory yourself with `int* deduped=new[newArraySize]();` and `delete deduped;`, or making a local array with a compile-time-constant maximum size (1000), and separately keeping track of how many elements you're actually using.

Comment: The objectives for the project I am working on state that I have to use one-dimensional arrays for this task, unfortunately. I appreciate the insight and would probably use it had the objective not required the array.

Comment: @JacobThompson There are no variable-length arrays in C++. You need to accomplish your objective using something else. A constant-size array perhaps? You also may wish to clarify what exactly is meant by "array" in your assignment.

Answer (score -1):

`newArraySize` is not declared const. Do that and it'll work.

Comment: The issue here is that newArraySize isn't constant. That is why I assign it to the value fin. Before that I make a new array size based on duplicates of an array a user assigns.

Comment: @JacobThompson Then you really need to update your question. If you want a variable-length array, obviously the number of elements cannot be const...

Comment: If it isn't constant, then you can't make a statically sized array based on it. Use a `std::vector`, or even a pointer and `new`/`delete`..